# Design Pattern for relation ship between menus and other part of application

Tags: c#, design-patterns

i am looking for this article but not able to find it any where **Use Design Patterns to Simplify the Relationship Between Menus and Form Elements in .NET**. It looks like MSDN has removed it? Does any one know where i can find it?

Actually i am looking for a Design pattern that i can use for relation ship between menu and other part of application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org) is a great tool that you can use in case someone removed web page or site moved somewhere.

I found article you missed.

**Web Archive page**: [Use Design Patterns to Simplify the Relationship Between Menus and Form Elements in .NET](http://web.archive.org/web/20120212184957/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188928.aspx)

Also you can take a look to [Mediator](http://www.dotnetlead.com/design-patterns/mediator) pattern:

> The Mediator Design Pattern allows you to decouple the direct
>   communication between objects by introducing a middle object, the
>   mediator, that facilitates the communication between the objects.
>   Imagine you have a system where numerous objects communicate with each
>   other by holding the reference to other objects. As the number of
>   object grows and the references to other objects increases the system
>   becomes hard to maintain. The mediator pattern is designed to solve
>   this problem.

I think it's most useful patter for providing communication point between menu stuff and some other part of system.

PS: I already used this pattern in my plugin based SaaS portal architecture.

Comment: Thank You, appreciate it

Comment: hmm Can you give me example how did you use Mediator for menus if its possible for you? Coded example will be much better : )